# Simple Coin Change Maker Program in C

Tags: c

So I have to make a Coin Change Maker program where the user inputs the price and how much they gave to pay and the output has to be their change in quarters, dimes, nickles, pennies. For some reason my program won't give the right output. If I input the price as 40 cents and input the amount I paid as 50 cents it says the change required is 10 cents but 2 dimes so it's giving me an extra dime. If anyone can help me that'd be greatly appreciated.

```
int main()
{

    int numberOfQuarters =0;
    int numberOfDimes =0;
    int numberOfNickels =0;
    int numberOfPennies =0;

    int price;
    int paid;
    int change;



    printf("Please enter the price of your item in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &price);

    printf("Please enter the amount of money you gave in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &paid);

    change = (paid - price);
    printf("Change required: %d", change);

    while(change >= 25)
    {
        numberOfQuarters++;
        if(numberOfQuarters >0 )
        {
            change = (change - (numberOfQuarters * 25));
        }
        printf("\nNumber of Quarters:%d", numberOfQuarters);
    }

    while((change >= 10) && (change < 25))
    {
        numberOfDimes++;
        if(numberOfDimes > 1)
        {
            change = (change - (numberOfDimes * 10));
        }
    }
    while((change >= 5) && (change < 10))
    {
        numberOfNickels++;
        if(numberOfNickels >0)
        {
            change = (change - (numberOfNickels * 5));
        }
    }

    printf("\nThe number of quarters: %d", numberOfQuarters);
    printf("\nThe number of dimes: %d", numberOfDimes);
    printf("\nThe number of nickels: %d", numberOfNickels);
    printf("\nThe number of pennies: %d", change);

}
```

Comment: If you're after C why did you add the Python and Java tags? Besides that, did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: change "numberOfDimes > 1" to "numberOfDimes > 0"

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but it is recommended that you have `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of your program. Otherwise, the compiler issues a bunch of warnings (for me at least).

Answer (score 0):

A simple logical error.

change `if(numberOfDimes > 1)` to `if(numberOfDimes > 0)`.

Better yet, you don't need the `if` statements inside the blocks. If the program reaches inside the while loop, then the if statement is always going to be true.

Comment: thank you !! yeah i just took out the if statement all together and it worked perfectly !!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(change >= 25)
{
    numberOfQuarters++;
    if(numberOfQuarters >0 )
    {
        change = (change - (numberOfQuarters * 25));
    }
    printf("\nNumber of Quarters:%d", numberOfQuarters);
}
```

This structure is wrong because 2nd quarter will have twice more value and 3rd quarter will have third more value in this code. You don't need to multiply `numberOfQuarters` and you don't need to check if `numberOfQuarters` is positive because it must be positive after incrementing from zero (if overflow doesn't happen).

This segment should be like this:

```
while(change >= 25)
{
    numberOfQuarters++; /* add one more quarter */
    change = change - 25; /* subtract the value of one quarter because one is added */
    printf("\nNumber of Quarters:%d", numberOfQuarters);
}
```

Calculations for dimes and nickels should be done in this way, too.

The reason for two dimes are used is that for some reason you desided not to decrease values of dimes when there is only one dime.

Comment: As written, your code will print the number of quarters each time through the loop. I don't think this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

So since the main issue has already been addressed, at this point I might as well just propose another implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int numberOfQuarters =0;
    int numberOfDimes =0;
    int numberOfNickels =0;
    int numberOfPennies =0;

    int price;
    int paid;
    int change;

    printf("Please enter the price of your item in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &price);

    printf("Please enter the amount of money you gave in cents: ");
    scanf("%d", &paid);

    change = (paid - price);
    printf("Change required: %d", change);

    numberOfQuarters += change / 25;
    change %= 25;
    numberOfDimes += change / 10;
    change %= 10;
    numberOfNickels += change / 5;
    change %= 5;
    numberOfPennies = change;

    printf("\nThe number of quarters: %d", numberOfQuarters);
    printf("\nThe number of dimes: %d", numberOfDimes);
    printf("\nThe number of nickels: %d", numberOfNickels);
    printf("\nThe number of pennies: %d\n", change);

}
```

This way you avoid having any loop and just use division and reminder.